# Probability question with joint probability mass function

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$,$Y$ are discrete random variables with joint pmf: $f(X,Y)=\frac{1}{10}$ when $1\leq Y\leq X \leq 4$ where $X$,$Y$ are integers and 0 elsewhere. What's the pmf of $Y$?

This is a practice question for my class and the answer says that the pmf of $Y$ is $f(Y)=\frac{1}{10}(5-Y)$ which doesn't make sense to me.

I got $f(Y)=\frac{1}{10}(4-Y)$ by integrating (I know it's discrete but I don't know how else to do it) $X$ from $Y$ to 4 over the joint pmf.

Comment: Hint: use total probability.

Answer (score 2):

$P(Y=k) = \sum_{i=k}^4 P(X=i)P(Y=k|X=i) $

And observe that  $ P(X=i)P(Y=k|X=i) = P(X=i,Y=k) = 1/10$

Then you get what you want.

Comment: I'm still confused as to how we go from 1/10 to 1/10(5-Y) since i only goes from 1 to 4, which is 4 at most?